# Google Sheets API v4: batchGet not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can't get Google Sheets API v4 to return multiple range values using batchGet. It is giving the following error (although the documentation says it needs valueRanges[], all the ranges and spreadsheetId are correct): "Extra args block must be a javascript object literal. (line 2, file "Code")"

Could you please help sort it out? Thank you. Here is the code:

```
function readRange(spreadsheetId) {
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet("someSpreadSheetID", ["Sheet1!D7:F7", "Sheet1!J7:L7"]);
  Logger.log(response.values);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this modified script? In order to use this, please enable Sheet API v4 on API console and enable Sheet API v4 at Advanced Google Services.

#### Modified script :

```
function readRange(spreadsheetId) {
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(
    "someSpreadSheetID",
    {ranges: ["Sheet1!D7:F7", "Sheet1!J7:L7"]}
  );
  Logger.log(response.valueRanges);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, modified it to {ranges: ["Sheet1!D7:F7", "Sheet1!J7:L7"]}, it is not giving the error anymore. But the Logger.log result shows: undefined. It is not returning the values.

Comment: Sheet API v4 is enabled both on API console and Advanced Google services. Could it be that .batchGet is supported only if it is run with "service.spreadsheets.values" and is not supported if it is run with "Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values" like in the script above?

Comment: @Din Can you show us your current script? If you can do, please add it on your question using Edit button. And if you use ``Logger.log(response.values);`` in your original script, ``undefined`` is retrieved. If you want values of each cell, please use ``Logger.log(response.valueRanges);`` in my answer.

Comment: thank you very much. `Logger.log(response.valueRanges);` worked fine and it returned the values. Pity that Google does not show examples how to use in their docs.

Comment: @Din Welcome. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I made this in-depth tutorial on how to easily access the Google Sheets API V4. Let me know what you think!

https://medium.com/@inaguirre/google-sheets-api-tutorial-with-javascript-588f581aa1d9

It is pretty simple if you know how to use fetch().